# Thymeleaf: Как не генерировать на html-странице содержимое тегов, в которые передаётся null

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Прошу помощи в использовании Thymeleaf. Приложение генерирует html страницы, используя html-шаблон. На каждой сгенерированой странице я вывожу описание конкретного продукта. Для каждого продукта имеется список характеристик.
Например, как выводятся размеры:

```
<p>Dimensions: <span th:text="${dimension}">Dimension</span></p>
```

В span контейнер я получаю значение dimension, которое соотносится с этим продуктом. Вопрос:
Каким образом необходимо настроить тег p  в случае, если переменная dimension == null, чтобы Thymeleaf не генерировал этот тег вообще (как и его содержимое), либо оставлял его пустым?

Огромная просьба не постить ссылки на документацию. Многое оттуда уже было безуспешно перепробовано.

Comment: `(${dimension} ? '<p>Dimensions: <span th:text="${dimension}">Dimension</span></p>' : '')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `th:if`

```
<p th:if="${dimension}">Dimensions: <span th:text="${dimension}">Dimension</span></p>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, работает. так тупо, что упустил такой простой вариант из возможных.